# How to move border-bottom up on hover?

Tags: css

I want to transition border-bottom up on hover but cannot figure out how to make it work. Any suggestions?

```
.nav h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.nav h1 a:hover::after {
  padding-bottom: -8px;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: Note: There is no such a thing as negative padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to change the value of `bottom: value`.

```css
/*DEMO*/*,*::before,*::after{box-sizing:border-box}div{margin-top:3rem}

h1,
span {
  position: relative
}

h1:after,
span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px red solid;
  transition: .5s
}

h1:hover:after,
span:hover:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .5s
}
```

```html
<h1>Example block element</h1>

<div>
  <span>Inline element</span>
  <div>
```

Other method that may work is to set height of `:after` element and change it on hover.

Answer (score 1):

here is the simplest version 
transition of the border-bottom up 8px on hover (as asked by you)

```css
     body {background-color: #eee;}
    .nav {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
      margin: 20px;
      background: #ddd;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .nav:hover {
      width: 100px;
      height: 92px;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="nav"></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try using the following code:

```css
h1.nav {
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}

h1.nav:hover {
    line-height: 20px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="nav">Hey</h1>
<h1 class="nav">hello</h1>
<h1 class="nav">Hey</h1>
```

Hope this was what you intended to do.
If not please elaborate more.

Comment: This is perfect! However, I want to go slightly higher up than line-height: 0px; how might I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a simple background to create the border and easily adjust the position using `background-position`

```css
.box {
  font-size:30px;
  padding:8px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 1px;
  
  background-position:bottom 2px left 0;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position:bottom 20px left 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text </div>
```

You can also transition from bottom to top

```css
.box {
  font-size:30px;
  padding:8px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  background:linear-gradient(red,red) no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 1px;
  
  background-position:bottom;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"> some text </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Simple example of How to move border-bottom up on hover

```css
li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cool-link {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.cool-link::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    transition: width .3s;
}

.cool-link:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    //transition: width .3s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
    <li><a class="cool-link" href="#">A cool link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the border higher then use height instead of line height

```css
h1.nav:hover {
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
h1.nav {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="nav">Hey</h1>
<h1 class="nav">hello</h1>
<h1 class="nav">Hey</h1>
```